# Rails: how to access questions associated with a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am associating questions with users. Users has_many questions, and questions belongs to users. If I want to show on a user home page their own questions and only edit their own questions, how do I go about verifying this? I think a helper method is required to check whether the question does belong to the user and then, for example, (If question.belongs to user) then show edit link. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: u can check it as if question.user == current_user then show edit

Answer (score 1):

Limit the scope of your `find` to the user whose questions you want to search.

Basically...

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    # instead of this...
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])

    # do this:
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

For showing a user's own questions you can make use of the collection rendering:

```
<%= render current_user.questions %>
```

Make sure you have a questions/_question.html.erb view, this is called by rails with a local variable passed to it (as the name of the model e.g. `question`).

This will only show the questions associated with the user.

### edit

To add on meagars answer, you should redirect if the user tries to edit a question which doesn't belong to the user:

```
redirect_to :root if @question.blank?
```

Optionally show a notification to the user that they haven't got permission.